# A string is the same if they have the same length and differ at most by one letter

Tags: python

how would this be done? I did it with def, but is there a simpler way to do it without def, lambda, enumerate and whatnot?

```
def is_one_away(first: str, other: str) -> bool:
    
    skip_difference = {
        -1: lambda i: (i, i+1),
        1: lambda i: (i+1, i),
        0: lambda i: (i+1, i+1),
    }
    try:
        skip = skip_difference[len(first) - len(other)]
    except KeyError:
        return False

    for i, (l1, l2) in enumerate(zip(first, other)):
        if l1 != l2:
            i -= 1
            break

    remain_first, remain_other = skip(i + 1)
    return first[remain_first:] == other[remain_other:]
```

Comment: Should you take into account letter position? E.g. Is `cat` the same as `act`?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description, making it hard to reason about them. Also, just a hint: The more you optimize code, the less understandable it becomes. Hence, it needs more explanations in comments. Further, consider codereview.stackexchange.com, if that's what you're after, but make sure to read their site guidelines first. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, the following should work:

```
def is_one_away(first,other):
    return len(first) == len(other) and sum(x != y for x,y in zip(first,other)) <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a clean versin of code that works.

```py
def is_one_away(first: str, other: str) -> bool:
    
    # check lengths
    if len(first) != len(other):
        return False
    
    error_count = 0
    for i in range(len(first)):
        if first[i] != other[i]:
            error_count += 1
            if error_count > 1:
                return False
    
    return True
```

Here are some checks:

```
# some checks
a, b = 'hello', 'world'
result = is_one_away(a,b)
print(result)

a, b = 'hi', 'world'
result = is_one_away(a,b)
print(result)

a, b = 'world', 'world'
result = is_one_away(a,b)
print(result)

a, b = 'worlf', 'world'
result = is_one_away(a,b)
print(result)

a, b = 'worff', 'world'
result = is_one_away(a,b)
print(result)
```

Here is the result of the checks (as expected):

```
False
False
True
True
False
```

Comment: Very clean indeed. How would I incorporate this into a code. (leave def)

Comment: @izzy, effectively, this just replaces the code in the question. However, you are still using the function (def) whichever method you use because this is a re-usable block of code.